# Multiple pandas.dataframe to one csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have multiple pandas dataframes, and hope to write them as one CSV file. What is the most straightforward way?

For example, from following four dataframes,

[image]

how can I create below CSV?

[image]

**Note** The dataframes all have the same dimensions.

Comment: Do the dataframes all have the same shape?

Comment: @unutbu Yes. All the dataframes have the same shape.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A very straightforward way would be to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) pairs horizontally,  concat the results vertically, and write it all out using [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
 import pandas as pd

 pd.concat([
    pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1),
    pd.concat([df3, df4], axis=1)]).to_csv('foo.csv')
```

---

A possibly more memory-conserving way would be to write it piecemeal:

```
with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
     pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).to_csv(f)
with open('foo.csv', 'a') as f:
     pd.concat([df3, df4], axis=1).to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Omitting `headers=False` would repeat the headers.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to keep headers visible for df3 and df4? In my question, the destination CSV has four rows and third one is the headers of df3 and df4.

Comment: @MichaelTamillow Thanks!

Comment: @AmiTavory how to write each dataframe in diferent sheets of the same csv file

Comment: @S.EB That's mainly a question of how to read multiple sheets. It's fairly doable, but a separate question. Could you open one on it? Plenty will help you, and if you link here, I'll be happy to look at it too.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone that needs to append multiple dataframes to same csv vertically, you can use this:

```py
with open('all_dfs.csv','a') as f:
    for df in list_of_dfs:
        df.to_csv(f)
        f.write("\n")
```